# If (Event) then set array to nothing?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have a MySQL query that does a selection.  I then have a `$numrows` variable which I have set to `$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);`. If the value of `$numrows == 0`, I want the array variable I have to be set to empty.  I tried setting the array variable to `null` and `"";` but those don't work.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty an array

```
$array= array();
```

Delete it altogether

```
unset($array);
```

Comment: This still gives me errors... You see, I still call the variable, but I want the value to be empty.., is this possible?

Comment: It's giving me an undefined variable error, which I assume is because the variable has no value.

Comment: no, empty variable != undefined variable. Can you post some code?

Comment: Please disregard my question.  I simply had an error in my script.  Thanks for going through the trouble of answering my quesiton thoughh.

Comment: of course...have fun banging your head through the rest of it. I know that I enjoy it immensely lol